# Prettier removes parentheses around mathematical expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier

I am trying to slice the array based on the mathematical expressions in React. However, prettier extension does not let me do it as it removes parenthesis making the expression incorrect.

Here is example:

```
const paginateItems = items.slice(
      pageIndex * itemsPerPage,
      (pageIndex * itemsPerPage) * 2
    )
```

And prettier changes that to

```
const paginateItems = items.slice(
      pageIndex * itemsPerPage,
      pageIndex * itemsPerPage * 2
    )
```

How can I fix this so that it does not force my expression to be incorrect?

Comment: How is it making the expression incorrect? `(1 * 2) * 3` is same as `1 * 2 * 3`

Comment: It won't matter in this case right? try something like `(a-b)*c` just to make sure, if it does that you could log a bug

Comment: `console.log(2*3*4 === (2*3)*4)`

Answer (score 5):

> How can I fix this so that it does not force my expression to be incorrect?

It doesn't make your expression incorrect. `*` is left-associative, meaning that `a * b * c` is exactly the same as `(a * b) * c`. The parens in that code don't make any difference to the result.

If your expression were `pageIndex * (itemsPerPage * 2)`, the parens could make a difference to the result (in programming¹) if `itemsPerPage` were ***really*** big (by causing overflow during `itemsPerPage * 2` instead of causing overflow during `pageIndex * itemsPerPage`, assuming `pageIndex` is 2 or higher). So I would expect Prettier to leave them alone in that case. But with `(pageIndex * itemsPerPage) * 2`, the `()` don't have any effect at all.

---

¹ "in programming" — In the world of mathematics, the parens in `pageIndex * (itemsPerPage * 2)` wouldn't make any difference either, because multiplication is *transitive* (I think that's the word): `a * b * c` is the same as `(a * b) * c` is the same as `a * (b * c)`. But in programming we deal with number types that have limited ranges and/or limited precisions at large magnitudes, so the order in which the two multiplication operations happen matters.

Comment: Quick inadequate experimentation suggests that the tool in question (Prettier) follows the rules of eliminating `( )` only when they imply the default order of operations.

Comment: In this example (all multiplication) it doesn't matter, and prettier may always get it correct, but I want groupings for readability.

Comment: @Ashbury - In that case, since I don't think Prettier has an option to turn that aspect of formatting off, I think you have just three options: 1. Don't use Prettier; or, 2. Disable Prettier for that expression (by using `// prettier-ignore` just before it), or 2. Write the grouping to a temporary variable: if you want `x = a * (b * c);`, do `const temp = b * c; x = a * temp;`.